# Get common part between two strings c#

Tags: c#, string, linq

What I need is to get the common part between two words and get the differences too.

Examples:

**Scenario 1**

- word1 = **Testimonial**
- word2 = **Test**

Will return

- Common part **Test**, difference **imonial**

**Scenario 2**

- word1 = **Test**
- word2 = **Testimonial**

Will return

- Common part **Test**, difference **imonial**

**Scenario 3**

- word1 = **Testimonial**
- word2 = **Tesla**

Will return

- Common part **Tes**, difference **timonial** and **la**

The common part of both words are always on the beginning.

In other words, I need to preserve the begin of the word until the words get different, than I need to get the differences.

I'm trying to do that avoid using a lot of if's and for's.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Is the common part always at the beginning of both strings? Also, share what you tried already.

Comment: Yes the commom part is always on the beginning of both strings.

Comment: Look for "type-ahead search techniques". This is a well-know problem -- with solutions.

Comment: I don't see anything complex .. compare the first characters in both strings, then the the second, etc.. until you find the index of the first different character, and get the substrings using that index.

Comment: What about a scenario where string1 is abcdef and string2 is cde what do you expect?

Comment: @hpfs this scenario will not happen. Only strings that match the beginning are allowed. In other wors, at least the first letter needs to be equal to do go  through this algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string word1 = "Testimonial";
        string word2 = "Tesla";

        string common = null;
        string difference1 = null;
        string difference2 = null;

        int index = 0;
        bool same = true;

        do
        {
            if (word1[index] == word2[index])
            {
                common += word1[index];
                ++index;
            }
            else
            {
                same = false;
            }

        } while (same && index < word1.Length && index < word2.Length);

        for (int i = index; i < word1.Length; i++)
        {
            difference1 += word1[i];
        }

        for (int i = index; i < word2.Length; i++)
        {
            difference2 += word2[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(common);
        Console.WriteLine(difference1);
        Console.WriteLine(difference2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

LINQ alternative:

```
string word1 = "Testimonial", word2 = "Tesla";

string common = string.Concat(word1.TakeWhile((c, i) => c == word2[i]));

string[] difference = { word1.Substring(common.Length), word2.Substring(common.Length) };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intersect` and `Except` to get it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var string1 = "Testmonial";
    var string2 = "Test";

    var intersect = string1.Intersect(string2);
    var except = string1.Except(string2);

    Console.WriteLine("Intersect");

    foreach (var r in intersect)
    {
        Console.Write($"{r} ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Except");

    foreach (var r in except)
    {
        Console.Write($"{r} ");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note that this is a simple solution. For example:
Except would not work if you change the order of the strings, like :

```
"Test".Except("Testmonial");
```

Comment: Now add "Monkey Test" to your test set...