# compare and display only the non-uniquepart of strings

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have 3 Strings :

> APPLESOFT
>
> MICROSOFT
>
> GOOGLESOFT

I need to compare these strings and display only the non-uniquepart in the UI like :

> APPLE...
>
> MICRO...
>
> GOOGLE...

How do i acheive it ??

```
ArrayList() a1 = new ArrayList();
a1.Add('APPLESOFT');
a1.Add('MICROSOFT');
a1.Add('GOOGLESOFT');
processStr(a1);


 public void processStr(ArrayList a1){
        .......
 }
```

Comment: you can use suffix array https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

Comment: I think this is same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074563/get-common-part-between-two-strings-c-sharp)

Comment: @Badiparmagi : Got it . Thank You

Comment: @user3383301 it does work. i tested myself now?

Comment: It works in case of softgoogle and softmicro but doesnot work in case of applesoft and microsoft